# How to add list of objects of Fragment to PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have PagerAdapter class that handle ScreenSlider. What i want is to add instance(objects of Fragment class) instead of adding multiple Fragments

Class where PagerAdapterClass is called:

```
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();        

    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment1.class.getName()));// Here i want to add instance of class
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Fragment2.class.getName()));    

    this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter2(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments); //Constructor

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

    pager.setCurrentItem(Proba.broj);
```

And here is PagerAdapter class:

```
public class PagerAdapter2 extends FragmentPagerAdapter

{

private List<Fragment> fragments;
/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public PagerAdapter2(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add an instance then.

```
fragments.add(new Fragment1()) ;
```

Or if you need arguments

```
Fragment f = new Fragment1();
Bundle args1 = new Bundle() ;
// put into args1
f.setArguments(args1);
fragments.add(f) ;
```

Related: [When Fragment.instantiate is preferable over MyFragment.newInstance or new MyFragment()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738570/when-fragment-instantiate-is-preferable-over-myfragment-newinstance-or-new-myfra)

> instead of adding multiple Fragments

You have to add multiple Fragments if you want multiple pages

Comment: But how to add another instace of Fragment1 with diffrent argumets?

Comment: You copy paste that exact line again. You never used arguments in the question, so I don't know what you mean

Comment: Well this instances have diffrent arguments, same member class but with diffrent values..